# What happens to RLS when join tables (Bigquery)

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, row-level-security

I use Bigquery to query data and RLS has been implemented to my tables.
I created a table and joined 2 different tables, with respectively C1 and C2 security : how the RLS is handled with a joined table ? My new table has a C1 or a C2 security (C2 is more restrictive than C1) ?

Best Regards,
Rinn

Comment: Only the row that you can access are taken into account.

Answer (score 0):

RLS of the resulting table will be determined by the most restrictive security level of the joined tables. In this case, the new table will inherit the C2 security level.
This is just because the joined table most likely contains information from the more restrictive table (C2), so it must be protected at least as strictly as that table.

Comment: Thanks for your reply ! Does we have the same behavior for created views (with joined tables) ?

Comment: I am not too sure about views, maybe you can test with a temporary role. But I think the saved view should also inherit the most restrictive RLS of the 2 tables.